# Get filenames without path of a specific directory

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get all filenames of a directory (and its subdirectorys) without the full path? 
**Directory.GetFiles(...)** returns always the full path!

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can extract the filename from full path.

#### .NET 3, filenames only

```
var filenames3 = Directory
                .GetFiles(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```

#### .NET 4, filenames only

```
var filenames4 = Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(Path.GetFileName); // <-- note you can shorten the lambda
```

#### Return filenames with relative path inside the directory

```
// - file1.txt
// - file2.txt
// - subfolder1/file3.txt
// - subfolder2/file4.txt

var skipDirectory = dirPath.Length;
// because we don't want it to be prefixed by a slash
// if dirPath like "C:\MyFolder", rather than "C:\MyFolder\"
if(!dirPath.EndsWith("" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)) skipDirectory++;

var filenames4s = Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(f => f.Substring(skipDirectory));
```

#### confirm in LinqPad...

```
filenames3.SequenceEqual(filenames4).Dump(".NET 3 and 4 methods are the same?");

filenames3.Dump(".NET 3 Variant");
filenames4.Dump(".NET 4 Variant");
filenames4s.Dump(".NET 4, subfolders Variant");
```

*Note that the `*Files(dir, pattern, behavior)` methods can be simplified to non-recursive `*Files(dir)` variants if subfolders aren't important*

Comment: In .NET 4, you can also do `Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(Path.GetFileName)`. The difference between `GetFiles` and `EnumerateFiles` is that for the former, you have to wait for the whole list to be populated before you can start looping through it, which with the latter you can start processing the first few files while the OS is still listing the other ones.

Comment: plz can u explain me in .Net 3
where Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)); 
how is "f" is used

Comment: @KiranSolkar `f => Path.GetFileName(f)` is a lambda expression and `f` is a string argument for this particular lambda. Lambdas are anonymous functions that you can use to create delegates or expression tree types. The type of arguments are inferred, so it is equivalent to `(string fullPath) => Path.GetFileName(fullPath)`. With C# 4 the type inferrence was improved, so you no longer need to write a lambda expression as long as you give it a method which takes a single string argument and returns something.

Comment: @drzaus Thanks for editing my response and providing more consistent examples

Comment: I checked the performance of both methods on .NET4 and EnumerateFiles is almost twice faster.

Comment: Path.GetFileName() method will do the above matter.

Answer (score 22):

See [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

> Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.

The [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) Class has several useful filename and path methods.

Answer (score 13):

You want [`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename)

This returns just the filename (with extension).

If you want just the name without the extension then use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension)

Answer (score 6):

You can just extract the file name from the full path.

```
var sections = fullPath.Split('\\');
var fileName = sections[sections.Length - 1];
```

Comment: Note that this implementation only works on Windows... Linux and Mac use `/`

Answer (score 6):

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
path, result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although several right answers are there for this questions, You may find this solution as:

```
string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Something", "*.*")
                 .Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p))
                 .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".bmp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || s.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a DirectoryInfo object, use a search pattern to enumerate, then treat it like an array.

```
string filePath = "c:\Public\";
DirectoryInfo apple = new DirectoryInfo(@filepath);
foreach (var file in apple.GetFiles("*")
{
   //do the thing
   Console.WriteLine(file)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the files name of particular directory using `GetFiles()` method of the `DirectoryInfo` class.
Here are sample example to list out all file and it's details of particular directory

```
System.Text.StringBuilder objSB = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("d:\\");
    objSB.Append("<table>");
    objSB.Append("<tr><td>FileName</td>" + 
                 "<td>Last Access</td>" + 
                 "<td>Last Write</td>" + 
                 "<td>Attributes</td>" + 
                 "<td>Length(Byte)</td><td>Extension</td></tr>");

    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo objFile in directory.GetFiles("*.*"))
    {
        objSB.Append("<tr>");

        objSB.Append("<td>");
        objSB.Append(objFile.Name);
        objSB.Append("</td>");

        objSB.Append("<td>");
        objSB.Append(objFile.LastAccessTime);
        objSB.Append("</td>");

        objSB.Append("<td>");
        objSB.Append(objFile.LastWriteTime);
        objSB.Append("</td>");

        objSB.Append("<td>");
        objSB.Append(objFile.Attributes);
        objSB.Append("</td>");

        objSB.Append("<td>");
        objSB.Append(objFile.Length);
        objSB.Append("</td>");

        objSB.Append("<td>");
        objSB.Append(objFile.Extension);
        objSB.Append("</td>");

        objSB.Append("</tr>");
    }
    objSB.Append("</table>");

    Response.Write(objSB.ToString());
```

This example display list of file in HTML table structure.