# to get the file names in a directory (without getting path) in c#

Tags: c#, filenames, arrays

i want to store the name of all file  present in `c:\test\` in a string `array s[]`

let there are files name `a1.txt , a2.txt , a3.txt ...` in c:\test

i want to store in `s[0]= a1.txt s[1]= a2.txt` and like that

i have used the code

```
s = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\test");
```

but it makes `s[0]= c:\test\a1.txt`
i dont want `c:\test` , i only want `a1.txt`

so is there any method to store only the file name but not the path of the file

i would also like to know if there is any method to remove some characters from each string of a string array

like cutting 5 characters from the beginning of each string of a string array  this may also solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried any basic functions of "String"? or even Googled?

Comment: do you have any answers? lol

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get filenames without path of a specific directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817639/get-filenames-without-path-of-a-specific-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to extract file name from path. Like below

```
string[] s = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\test");
foreach (string filename in s)
{     
    string fname = Path.GetFileName(filename);
}
```

Comment: @c_sharp boy I am glad you are able to find solution, please accept this answer if it helped.

Comment: for (x = 0; x < s.Length; x++)
                s[x] = Path.GetFileName(s[x]);

Answer (score 0):

maybee duplicate from [hare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817698/1509853)..
any way @Vasea gives us :

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```