# Check if the two Files exist in the folder

Tags: c#, .net

I want to take file name from user as *.txt only, and compare the file name *.txt first with General.txt and then with special.txt.If both the files are present in the folder then boolean is set true.

Alteration to the question:-
Checking file count with *.txt file name
If count is 2 then our purpose is solved

Comment: your try so far ? post with efforts taken

Comment: And the problem is ??

Comment: Even though your name means that you are new to coding, you have to understand that coding is not just about copy pasting someone else's code. You have to try things, learn things, fail things. Then come and ask.

Comment: i am an only able to achieve the comparison of exact file names which the user eventually have to enter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817639/get-filenames-without-path-of-a-specific-directory

Comment: So do you mean you want to take a full path name "C:\Folder1\Folder2\\*.txt" from the user and check if General.txt & special.txt are both in  "C:\Folder1\Folder2\". If not can you give us an example of input & expected output.

Comment: @PaulF yes this what i am asking

Comment: If i make little alteration to the problem, i would say on the basis of *.txt, i would check if the File count is 2 in the folder then flag(boolean) is set

Comment: @ArthurRey Sorry man... I understand the ethics but i was not going to copy - paste, i just wanted the correct method for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
        string path = @"";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
        if (files.Length >= 2)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var generalTxt = new FileInfo("General.txt");
var specialTxt = new FileInfo("special.txt");

if (generalTxt.Exists && specialTxt.Exists) { //is true if both files exist }
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the answer to _"I want to take file name from user as *.txt only, and compare the file name *.txt first with General.txt and then with special.txt"_

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
string FullPath = Path.GetFullPathName(userstring);
string path1 = Path.Combine(FullPath, "General.txt");
string path2 = Path.Combine(FullPath, "special.txt");
bool Flag = File.Exists(path1) && File.Exists(path2);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, But i think this would hardcode the things. The alteration to the question is that how would i check if the File.txt count is 2 in the folder then flag(boolean) is set