# Remove path to file from textbox when file selected C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, select, path, dialog, openfiledialog

Hello I am trying to select a file from a directory from my Windows Form application, but I can't seem to find anything that will remove the path from the text box and keep only the file name (Example: "C:\Users\Users\Documents\File.txt" would be just "File.txt") where it saves the output when file is selected.

```
         OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

         openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\OUTPUT";
         openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse exe Files";

         openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
         openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
         openFileDialog1.Filter = "exe files | *.exe";

         openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "exe";
         openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
         openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

         openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
         openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;

         if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             textBox6.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
         }
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817639/get-filenames-without-path-of-a-specific-directory

Comment: Just to clarify, since I'm a little unclear on what your specific issue is: the path name is showing up in the text box of the dialog, and you want the text box to just be blank?

Comment: @MathSquared What OP wanted was to remove the path to file and leave only it's name. Example "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Text.txt" would be just "Text.txt"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) function for this.

```
 textBox6.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: i did this : string Path = @"C:\OUTPUT";
And it gave me this error : 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetFileName' and no extension method 'GetFileName' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Path is not a string variable, but a name of a class. I edited the answer to make it clearer.